# Iframe loaded upon click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, iframe, onload

I have multiple iframes in my page which is slowing my web page down a lot.

How can I tackle this?

My idea is to onload each iframe? 
e.g

```
    $('iframe').each(function() {
          $('iframe').onload();
    });
```

Any help would be great.

**EDIT**

I realised that I could load the iframe src upon click event from comments below so I have adapted my answer below.

Comment: Do you have to load all the iframes at the same time? Can you not just load an individual iframe on a click event or similar? Also, `.onload` is JavaScript, not jQuery; you might be looking for `.load()`. However, in terms of performance, I would recommend `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Yes is a click event which opens up a modal box to display iframe, ahh so I would do a onclick onload iframe?

Comment: Seems like what you want is the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16715859/215552)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable iframes automatic onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715859/disable-iframes-automatic-onload)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you @Mike McCaughan & @Obsidian Age - I have adapted your reference and got it working. Page speed is great now!

Removed src="" from iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('a[data-reveal-id="corporate-profile"]').click(function() {document.getElementById("corporate-profile-iframe").src = "http://www.example.com/resources/corporate-profile/index.html";
    ...
    ...
    (multiple accounts of iframes)
});
```

Comment: If this is the answer, you need to edit your question. This is not related at all as far as I can see.